# Getting certificate-related error when downloading Kotlin into Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

So I'm trying to install Kotlin into Android Studio. I believe it is installed, but I get an error when Gradle tries to build the project. This is where my error comes in.

**The problem:**

When Gradle tries to build the project, it gives me this error:

> ***Error: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target***

This is my build.gradle project file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `google maven` central repository.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // This one
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // And this one
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```